# SimplePie error in Wordpress error log

Tags: php, wordpress

I keep getting this message in my Wordpress error log. I do not have SimplePie installed but to try and get rid of the message I installed a copy of SimplePie through the Wordpress plugin installer and then deleted it. Any suggestions?

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
'/var/www/sites/ptsail.org/public_html  /wp-includes/class-feed.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
/var/www/sites/ptsail.org/public_html/wp-includes/feed.php on line
530, referer: http://ptsail.org/wp-admin/
```

line 530 from feed.php is in a section about SimplePie and reads

```
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-feed.php' );
```

I do not have a file called class-feed.php in /wp-includes

Thanks, Jon

Comment: /var/www/sites/ptsail.org/public_html/wp-includes/feed.php is requiring the class-feed.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if `php-curl` is installed on your server
These are php extensions that need to installed for wordpress server

```
php-curl php-gd php-mbstring php-xml php-xmlrpc php-soap php-intl php-zip
```